# Auto Eat between double damage?

Tags: melvor-idle

The bandit leader in the bandit base dungeon has as special attack:

*Rapid Fire:
An avoidable attack that deals 100% of the enemy's normal damage **2 times**.*

Now i wonder, does auto eat work between the two times damage dealed? Or is the two times damage dealed combined without option to eat between.

That is important for my hardcore char, because double damage could kill him if no food is eaten between the first and second damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it by myself and can confirm that autoeat works between the 2 times damage dealed. It also works for Dragon breath (An unavoidable attack that deals 30x20 damage over 2.85s.) between the single damages and other multiple damage sources.